How to convert Opus audio file to mp3 with maximum quality use FFmpeg?
How to convert Opus audio file to mp3 with maximum quality use FFmpeg? Linux.
Source audio file is Opus, stereo 48 kHz, 138 kbps, Bits per sample:32
I used
ffmpeg -i audio.opus -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 newfile.mp3
which gave me VBR audio with an average bitrate about 273 kb/s.

That would be -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k
Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3
There's no discernible difference between -b 320 and -V 0 (-q:a 0, that you used), so there's no point overshooting with the bitrate.

Is it possible to objectively determine which of the two methods -b:a 320k or -q:a 0 has better sound quality? Without using human hearing (which is subjective), but by comparing audio files with a analyzer program or script.

Sadly with audio the human ear is something that you need to trust as we've not invented better. There's a whole forum dedicated to that: https://hydrogenaud.io/ Both -V 0 and -b 320 are transparent for 99.99% of audio tracks out there for 99.99% of people. And MP3 is severly outdated, there are much better codecs nowadays. E.g. AAC/Opus at 128kbsp are as good as MP3 at 320kbps. And if you care about audio preservation then stick to lossless audio, e.g. FLAC.

From a mathematical point of view, all other things being equal, the more different frequencies are present in the signal spectrum, the higher the audio quality. This way we can measure the number of frequencies present in each of the audio samples and compare them.

Hearing doesn't work truly mathematically which is why lossy audio compression formats exist. They remove the things we don't hear.
